# WPF DataGrid Nested Bands - Remove previous selected row color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a banded WPF DataGrid where if you select the top band, the row will go blue to signify that it is the selectedRow (By default). However, when the user then selects a row from the second band, I want the blue color from the top band to disappear, as this means **its hard to spot what row you have selected further down the hierarchy**.

is this possible through XAML or C#?

Through XAML I could use something like this on each band (RowDetailsTemplate)

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Blue" />
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="2" />
           </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

And through c# I can get the selectedRow when they click on a row

```
DataGridRow selectedRow = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(expandCollapseButton);
```

So I have a couple of possibilities but I need help to get "the previous row and then uncolor it"

Cheers

Comment: could you please share some screens of current and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to deselect the selected row in a `DataGrid` when a row becomes selected *from the second band* (whatever that is). One simple way to remove the selection from a `DataGrid` is to simply set the `SelectedItem` property to `null`:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

Then in code behind, when the other row is selected (possibly in a `SelectionChanged` event handler), you can simply call this:

```
private void SecondBandSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Comment: Cheers make sense, the second band is just the DataGrid.RowsDetailTemplate for that row. a Band is a genetic word for it, especially in the infragistics lirbary